# Conflicting REST urls

Tags: rest, architecture

So I'm building a REST api and need to make some urls. The problem is, I'm running into some conflicting paths. For example:

- `GET <type>/<id>` gets the details of an object of a given type and id
- `GET <type>/summary` gets the summary of objects of a given type

This simplified example shows a problem occurs when an object has id "summary". What is the best way to solve this? From a REST puritan perspective, what should be the solution?

Here's some of my ideas:

- Put the `<id>` in query parameters. From what I understand this is against standards
- Put a keyword at the start of the url. Also against standards?
- Disallow certain id values. Not something I want to enforce for all my users and use cases and different entrances into my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL structure is not quite right to begin with so it's difficult to solve it in a clean way.

For the sake of discussion, let's assume `<type>` is a `books` resource. So the first URL is fine - you get a book of the given ID:

```
GET /books/<id>
```

However this is not:

```
GET /books/summary
```

Because it's a bespoke URL, which I guess has a use in your application but is not restful. A GET call should return one or more resources. However a "summary" is not a resource, it's a *property* of a resource and that's why you end up in this situation of having IDs mixed up with book properties.

So your best option would be to change this URL to something like this:

```
GET /books?fields=summary
```

By default `GET /books` would return all the resources, while `GET /books?fields=<list_of_fields>` will return the books but with only the chosen properties.

That will be similar to your previous URL but without the ID/property conflict, and will also allow you later on to retrieve resources with specific fields (without having to create new custom URLs).

**Edit:**

Regarding the count of books, it's still useful to reason in terms of resources. `/books` gives you one or more books, but it should *not* be used for meta-information about the collection, such as count, but also things like "most read book", or "books that start with the letter 'A'", etc. as that will make the resource more and more complex and difficult to maintain.

Depending on what you want to achieve I think there'd be two solutions:

1. Create a new resource that manages the collection of books. For example:

   GET /bookcase

And that will give you information about the collection, for example:

```
{
    "count": 1234,
    "most_read": "<isbn>",
    // etc. - any information that might be needed about the book collection
}
```

2. Or a search engine. You create a resources such as:

   GET /book_search_engine/?query=

which would return a search result such as:

```
{
    "count": 123,
    "books": [
        // Books that match the query
    ]
}
```

then a query like this would give you just the count:

```
// Search all the books, but provide only the "count" field
GET /book_search/?query=*&fields=count
```

Obviously that's a more involved solution and maybe not necessary for a simple REST API, however it can be useful as it makes it easier to create queries specific to a client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand what you mean but it isn't completely satisfying for me. What if, for example, I want to get the count of all books. How would I put that in a url? "count" wouldn't be a field of a set of resources in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidtenHove, I think there's a few ways to deal with "count" and other such meta-information. I've updated my answer with two possible solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I may have an alternative to this. What if we have both book as wel as the plural books. Then you can have:

```
/book/{id}
```

and

```
/books/summary
```

or

```
/books/count
```

Answer (score 2):

> This simplified example shows a problem occurs when an object has id "summary". What is the best way to solve this? From a REST puritan perspective, what should be the solution?

As far as *REST* is concerned, the URI are opaque.  Spelling is absolutely irrelevant.  You could use URI like

```
/a575cc90-2878-41fe-9eec-f420a509e1f0
/f871fff6-4c4e-48f7-83a4-26858fdb3096
```

and as far as REST is concerned, that's spot on.  See Stefan Tilkov's talk [REST: I Don't Think It Means What You Think It Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).

What you are asking about is *URI design*, how to adapt conventions/best practices to your particular setting.

One thing that will help is to recognize is that summary is a *resource*, in the REST/HTTP sense -- it is a document that can be represented as a byte sequence.  All you need to do is figure out where that resource belongs (according to your local spelling conventions).

Continuing to borrow the "books" example used by others

```
# Here's the familiar "URI that identifies a member of the books collection"
/books/<id>

# Here's the summary of the /books collection
/summaries/books
```

> Put the  in query parameters. From what I understand this is against standards

Not as much as you might think.  REST doesn't care.  The [URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) expresses some views about hierarchical vs non hierarchical data.  HTTP supports the notion of a *redirect*, where one resource can reference another.

```
GET /books?id=12345

302 Found
Location: /books/12345
```

You also have options for skipping a round trip, by returning the representation you want immediately, taking advantage of [Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2)

```
GET /books?summary

200 OK
Content-Location: /summaries/books

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. And all the solutions seem a little off b/c REST best practices seem to suggest none of them are ideal.

You could have just *one* off-limit id, like `all`.

- `GET <type>/<id>`
- `GET <type>/all/summary`

It might even be possible to use a single symbol instead, such as `~` or `_`.

- `GET <type>/<id>`
- `GET <type>/~/summary`

How satisfying this solution seems is of course very subjective.

The singular/plural approach seems more elegant to me but despite most REST best practice guides saying not to do this. Unfortunately some words don't have distinct singular and plural forms.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfectly conventional for how some like to define their rest endpoints.

But I would would enforce a pattern where "id" cannot be any string. Instead I would use a uuid and define my routes as such.

`GET /books/{id:uuid}`

`GET /books/{id:uuid}/summary`

And if you really want a verb in the URL without an identifier it is still technically possible because we know the `{id:uuid}` in the path must conform to the uuid pattern.

With that `GET /books/summary` is still distinct from `GET /books/{id:uuid}`